# RuntimeError: Optimal parameters not found: Number of calls to function has reached maxfev

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I've hit this error when trying to run `scipy.optimize.curve_fit()` to fit a sinusoidal curve to data. Looking at other questions, I've tried increasing the value of `maxfev` all the way to a million and it still won't converge.

I also checked whether the array I have in for sigma (which isn't actually the error as we don't have that but a rough approximation) has any zeroes in it as that would cause it to trip up but it doesn't. It does hit a divide by zero error sometimes but I don't know what's causing it and I can't replicate it consistently.

This is the data I am fitting; it clearly has a sinusoidal trend and I've set the initial parameters to match the plot as well as I can.

[image]

It works when I have a smaller time range; it's only the larger datasets it gets stuck on.

[image]

This is the line of code:

```
params, params_covariance = optimize.curve_fit(test_func, array, avg_radon, p0=[naverage_true,nstd,np.pi/365,1], sigma = npercent,maxfev=10000)
```

Where the function to be fitted is

```
def test_func(x, P0, P1, P2, P3):
        return P0 + P1 * np.sin(P2*(x-P3))
```

and the initial parameters are the average of the function, the standard deviation (amplitude), a period of a year, and the shift I'm not really sure of. I've also tried initializing with the optimal parameters of the smaller dataset and no dice.

Again just to reiterate: I've tried increasing `maxfev` and checking `sigma` for zeroes, which are the solutions suggested in all the other questions of this form I can find.

**Edit:** I figured out that I get the divide by zero error only if I run the larger dataset directly after having run the smaller dataset. What could that mean?